# hiding the testcase execution status as well report path

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have created a robot framework tool with one testcase.
now 'its showing testcase execution status "Pass" and well report path.
I need to turn off the testcase execution status as well as report path.

[image]

Expected to turn off the below details showing in termial

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68267627/console-logging-from-robot-framework-listeners-using-pythons-logging  it looks like similar issue

Answer (score 1):

add `--quiet` option

```
Example : python3 -m robot --quiet test.robot
```

REF : https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#controlling-console-output